# Error converting

Tags: java, android

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user2.trafficmap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'io.nlopez.smartlocation', name: 'library', version: '3.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile ('com.schibstedspain.android:leku:3.6.2',{
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and I get this Error

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse
>   version 52 byte code. This is caused by library dependencies that have
>   been compiled using Java 8 or above. If you are using the 'java'
>   gradle plugin in a library submodule add  targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>   sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that submodule's build.gradle file.

I want to add leku library to my project and I have this problem
how can I add target and source compatibility to my sub module ???

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative 1

Move

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

before `dependencies`

---

### Alternative 2

Use Android studio 3 and java 8. Change build tools

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

and

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        // ...        
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries you set with source compat to java 8 can't be added when you manually set the app itself to run on Java 7. Meaning this:

```
compile ('com.schibstedspain.android:leku:3.6.2',{
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
})
```

changes to:

```
compile ('com.schibstedspain.android:leku:3.6.2',{
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
})
```

Note that if the library itself is compiled with Java 8, this is most likely not going to work.

Alternatively, compile your app with Java 8:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

If you're using Android Studio < 3, you have to use Jack. If you're using Android Studio >= 3, don't use Jack. It's not needed and it's deprecated.

As for the error itself:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.

Bytecode version is related to Java version

> This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.

The `'com.schibstedspain.android:leku:3.6.2'` dependency

> If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add targetCompatibility = '1.7' sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that submodule's build.gradle file.

I.e. compile the library with Java 7 instead of Java 8.

Since this could be caused by the targetCompatibility part in the import, changing that to `1.7` should fix it. Alternatively, use Java 8 on your app to compile. <sub>You're not losing any platforms by doing this, it's supported on (AFAIK) all the versions. Though there are specific Java 8 API's that only are available in later versions of Android. E.g. streams that wasn't added until API 24</sub>

Comment: I do it but it show another Error  " Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8."

Comment: then you're not using AS 3 or newer. Add jack. AS 3.0 and newer supports Java 8 without jack, but older versions don't